# google fonts won't load with html

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm sure this question has been asked multiple times before. I have followed a lot of the advice, but none seems to work. I've been trying to load 'chelsea market' and caveat in my h1 line. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chelsea+Market' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<style>

h1 {
    font-family: ‘Chelsea Market’, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 200px; color: rgb(0, 0, 228); 
margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;

    }
```

Comment: What's the issue, what isn't working?

Comment: You are using invalid quote characters in the css `‘Chelsea Market’`

Comment: Open chrome devtools (or firefox), click the Network tab, load the page, and check the status code and response headers for the fonts and css from google.

Comment: THe problem is I can't load the actual fonts for 'chelsea market'. Everything else works except that. I've tried using double quotations"" as well and that didn't work either

Comment: nevermind, somehow it works now..thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `@import` instead off the regular link to the font?

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chelsea+Market');
font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;
```

Comment: Can I see the rest of your code? Your code doesn't actually have the h1 int the HTML.

Comment: yea sure, it's rather long though if you don't mind:

Comment: h1 {
    font-family: 'chelsea market', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 200px; color: rgb(0, 0, 228); 
margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
    
    }

p {
font-family: 'Caveat'; font-size: 33px; color: rgb(113, 218, 113); margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 450px; 
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>YALA</h1>
<p>Let's go places..</p>
</body>

Comment: do you have any other code? This code seems to work fine in [codepen](http://codepen.io/CookieMonsta/pen/EZdKRv).

Comment: That's it! but somehow the code does work now, not sure how. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I saw there is no `<body>` and `<h1>` tag in your code. I 've just tested out by copying your code and add `<body>` and `<h1>` tag, it works fine in my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/hoatran1403/pen/oBMExy?editors=1111) here

Comment: Hi hoath, i'm having trouble with the fonts. I want it to be in 'chelsea market'

Comment: @estelyk Seems like you have a problem when using google font together with bootstrap.css. I think you have to download bootstrap and make a custom for your own instead of using bootstrap CDN. This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075222/how-can-i-change-the-bootstrap-default-font-family-using-font-from-google