# How to change bootstrap.css font-family HTML to my own downloaded font

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I've tried to find how to do that, at least [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075222/how-can-i-change-the-bootstrap-default-font-family-using-font-from-google) almost got me. but she/he is using link to change the font.

but I've my own downloaded font using [font converter](https://font-converter.net/en) (.eot .otf .svg .ttf .woff .woff2)

and I have `style.css` like below:

```
/* font converted using font-converter.net. thank you! */
@font-face {
  font-family: "CataneoBT-Regular";

  src: url("./fonts/07323Cataneo.svg") format("svg"), /* Legacy iOS */
    url("./fonts/07323Cataneo.ttf") format("truetype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url("./fonts/07323Cataneo.woff") format("woff"), /* Modern Browsers */
    url("./fonts/07323Cataneo.woff2") format("woff2"); /* Modern Browsers */
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This is piece of code of my bootstrap.css html:

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

The most similar code of my bootstrap is:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')
  format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2')
  format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')
  format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')
  format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')
  format('svg');
}
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

but as far as I know, this code just to displaying some icon

I don't know how to change that code to displaying my own font

Comment: Are you using the compiled code or the source code (LESS, SASS)?

Comment: You don't really need to include all of these font formats. Woff is good enough. http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use following CSS to your CSS file which should include after `bootstrap`..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: <Your-font>;
    src: url(<your-font-path>);
}
html, body {
    font-family: <Your-font>, sans-serif; /*Specify your font name here*/
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what about the `@import` of the local font itself?

Comment: I've edited my post more details, and can i use `@font-face` twice?

Comment: like `@font-face_1`?

Comment: @RedRiver for reference check http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700

Answer (score 1):

In style.css file u need to link the font-family, give your font path in **src**

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'sans-serif';
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 src: url('../fonts/sans-serif.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/sans-serif.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/sans-serif.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/sans-serif.otf') format('opentype'), url('../fonts/sans-serif.svg#sans-serif') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: I want to change sans-serif font to my own downloaded font not the other way around