# Add Google Fonts to Bootstrap 4 with SASS / Gulp

Tags: bootstrap-4, google-fonts

I try to implement Google Fonts (Dosis) into Bootstrap 4 using SASS / Gulp. I'm a total novice when it comes to SASS.

I managed to change the default colors using `_custom.scss` by defining `$brand-primary`, but when I want to do the same with the fonts by changing `$font-family-sans-serif` value it doesn't work. I restarted the server and included the Google fonts in the index.html with `link` tags...but still I can't get it to work.

Comment: Although the [question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075222/how-can-i-change-the-bootstrap-default-font-family-using-font-from-google) is not sass and gulp specific, there is an excellent answer for your setup as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can import the chosen Google Font at the top of your *_custom.scss* like so.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis');
```

And you can define "Dosis" as a font family name like so:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: "Dosis", […other fonts…];
```

This should work once your sass is compiled.