# Change Font-family of nav-links in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do you change the font-family of nav-links in Bootstrap 5?  I tried,

```
.navbar a { 
  font-family: 'Custom-Font' !important; 
}

.navbar  { 
  font-family: 'Custom-Font' !important; 
}

.nav-link { 
  font-family: 'Custom-Font' !important; 
}
```

But none works.

Comment: You can refer below similar question asked earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075222/how-can-i-change-the-bootstrap-default-font-family-using-font-from-google

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I was able to change the `font-family` so easily. Maybe you forgot to add the font link or you didn't link it correctly to your CSS?

```
.navbar a {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

I also tried getting a font from Google Fonts, and it worked.

[image: result]

Here is a working example with Google Fonts.

```css
.navbar a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap 5-->
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- adding google fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- start navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control mr-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- JavaScript and dependencies -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```